# Graphviz: edges between cells in the same html table are too long

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to draw edges between cells in the same table node in graphviz, but the edges are way too long, which may overlap other nodes. How to make these edges shorter?

Here is an example.

```
digraph graphviz {
    graph [rankdir = "LR"];
    node [shape = "plaintext"];
    
    "A" [label=<
        <TABLE>
        <TR><TD PORT="a">cell a</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="b">cell b</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="c">cell c</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];
    
    "B" [label=<
        <TABLE>
        <TR><TD PORT="a">cell a</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="b">cell b</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];
    
    "A":"c" -> "A":"a";
    "A":"c" -> "A":"b";
    
    "B":"a" -> "A":"a";
}
```

I found a similar issue [Loopy edge too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023723/loopy-edge-too-long), but there is no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that simply adding a label on arbitrary edge solves the problem. If you don't want any text on edges, use spaces.

```
digraph graphviz {
    graph [rankdir = "LR"];
    node [shape = "plaintext"];
    
    "A" [label=<
        <TABLE>
        <TR><TD PORT="a">cell a</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="b">cell b</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="c">cell c</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];
    
    "B" [label=<
        <TABLE>
        <TR><TD PORT="a">cell a</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="b">cell b</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];
    
    "A":"c" -> "A":"a" [label=" "];
    "A":"c" -> "A":"b";
    
    "B":"a" -> "A":"a";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to produce smaller edges (less loopy):
`dot -Tdot myfile.gv |neato -n -Tpng >$myfile.png`
It uses **dot** to position the nodes and **neato** to position the edges.
See: https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords and https://graphviz.org/docs/outputs/canon/
Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Comment: In this approach, edges between nodes seem to become more straight and less flexible. Those edges may cross nodes. I am wondering if we could solve this problem just by modifying the source code? Is this a bug or something?